Why is my production database modified instead of the mock one I created for testing?
I am trying to write some tests for fastapi endpoints. However, I realized that I am not using the mock databases I thought I created ... but the real ones. What is happening? What am I missing?
This is what I have tried, for my test_main.py file:
import pytest
from FruitCaloriesApp.main import CaloriesCalculator, get_db, app
from FruitCaloriesApp.database import SessionLocal
from FruitCaloriesApp.models import FruitCalories, CaloriesHistory,Base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")  # In-memory SQLite database
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_session():
    # Create fruitcalories table in the in-memory database
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    db = SessionLocal()

    # Insert mock data to fruitcalories table
    apple = FruitCalories(fruit="apple", calories=20.3)
    pear= FruitCalories(fruit="pear", calories=10.3)

    db.add_all([apple, pear])
    db.commit()
    yield db  
    db.close()
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)

def test_calc_cals_apple(db_session):
    calculator = CaloriesCalculator(amount=3, fruit="apple", db=db_session)
    expected = 3 * 20.3
    assert calculator.calc_calories() == pytest.approx(expected, 0.001)



#2. Test End Points -------
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient       #create a client for our app, like app=Fastapi()
from CaloriesCalc import main  
from fastapi import status
from FruitCalcApp.main import app, CaloriesInput
from datetime import datetime

client = TestClient(main.app)
#/calculate_calories correct answer
def test_calculate_calories(db_session):
    apple_calories = db_session.query(FruitCalories).filter(FruitCalories.fruit == "apple").first().calories
    response=client.post("/calculate_calories",json={"amount": 3, "fruit": "apple"})
    assert response.status_code== status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert response.json() =={"fruit": "apple", "amount": 3, "total_calories": 3 * 20.3}

#/store_calories correctly returns expected results
def test_store_calories(db_session):
    response = client.post("/store_calories", json={"fruit": "apple", "amount": 3}, params={"user_id": 1})
    assert response.status_code == 201
    data = response.json()["data"]
    assert data["user_id"] == 1
    assert data["fruit"] == "apple"
    assert data["amount"] == 3
    expected = 3 * 20.3
    assert data["total_calories"] == pytest.approx(expected, 0.001)

And my main.py looks  like this:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Annotated, Optional, List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, status, HTTPException, Body, Path, Query
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from FruitCaloriesApp import models
from FruitCaloriesApp.models import FruitCalories
from FruitCaloriesApp.database import engine, SessionLocal
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

app = FastAPI()                    
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db=SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

db_dependency = Annotated[Session, Depends(get_db)]

class CaloriesInput(BaseModel):
    fruit: str
    calories: float  

class CaloriesHistoryResponse(BaseModel):   
    user_id: int
    date: str
    fruit: str
    amount: float
    total_calories: float

#OOP structure
class CaloriesCalculator():
    def __init__(self, amount: float, fruit: str, db: Session):
        self.amount = amount
        self.fruit = fruit
        self.db = db
        self.calories = self.get_calories()

    def get_calories(self):
        result = (self.db.query(FruitCalories.calories).filter(FruitCalories.fruit == self.fruit).first())
        if result:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return None

    def calc_calories(self):
        if self.calories is None:
            raise ValueError("valerror")     
        else:
            return self.amount * self.calories 

    def store_calories(self, db: Session, user_id: str, date, total_calories: float):
        calories_entry = CaloriesHistory(user_id=user_id, date=date, amount=self.amount,fruit=self.fruit,total_calories=total_calories)
        db.add(calories_entry)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(calories_entry)
        return calories_entry

@app.post("/store_calories", status_code = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def store_calories_fruit(data: CaloriesInput, user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        calculator = CaloriesCalculator(fruit=data.fruit, disamount=data.amount, db=db)
        total_calories = calculator.calc_calories()
        date=datetime.now().isoformat()
        calculator.store_calories(db, user_id, date, total_calories)
        
        return {
            "message": "Stored", 
            "data": {"user_id": user_id, "date":  date, "fruit": data.fruit, "amount": data.amount,"total_calories": total_calories}
            }

And then when I run pytest, I see that data is being added to my production database that has the table called calorieshistory. Why?

If you want to override SessionLocal in FruitCaloriesApp.database for your tests, you can do import FruitCaloriesApp.database; FruitCaloriesApp.database.SessionLocal = ... before you import anything from FruitCaloriesApp.main. Variables in modules can only be reassigned through the module reference.
Although, you can achieve what you're trying to do using FastAPI as well, via app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = db_session

thanks! hmm so I added app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: db_session to store_calories_fruit but now I'm getting an sqlite3 operational error that says that there is no such table , dou you have an idea of why  can this be? @Violet

You can add a models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) call in your test file to create the tables in the in-memory database.
